# Яйца "в мешочек"

Tags: пунктуация

Подумалось: а почему мы "яйца всмятку" или вкрутую пишем без кавычек, а "в мешочек" в кавычках? Все формы - это виды вареных яиц.
Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Способы варки яиц настолько важны,что в словаре существуют специальные слова для их обозначения:

ВСМЯТКУ, нареч.До полужидкого состояния (о способе варки яйца.

ВКРУТУЮ, нареч.До твёрдого состояния (о способе варки яйца).

А значение падежной формы "в мешочек" не столь очевидно, поэтому кавычки обозначают условность названия: это именно способ варки. Ведь мы можем просто положить яйцо в мешочек и взять его с собой на завтрак.